# Integrity while reading from two tables: orders and order_items

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions

I'm looking for a method of achieving data integrity while reading from the database (which does not use a lot of resources, hopefully), without adding new fields into the schema.

By integrity I mean the integrity between order sum in orders table and sum of order item prices:

```
orders (id PK, description text, amount decimal)
order_items (id PK, order int ref orders.id, item int ref items, price decimal)
items (id PK, description text)
```

It is important that the number of order_items can be quite big (several thousands) and it is not very practical to read all of them every time the complete order amount should be displayed. But when the order is exported, it should be correct, even though it can be updated in the same moment.

For example:

1. User A starts exporting the order.
2. System reads the order details: SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id=42
3. User B starts updating the order #42 so the new order items are added and the order amount is updated (within transaction, so the data in DB is coherent).
4. System continues with the second request to order details while fulfilling the exporting request: SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE order=42
5. And now the data in the export is not coherent as the order total amount does not match the amount obtained by summing order_items.

Is it better to open the transaction while exporting or just lock the two tables before reading from them?

The database is PostgreSQL.

BTW, this question should be quite basic so apologise for duplication, just did my best to search for the solution, but fail to find the clear one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to fetch a nice hot cup of tea and coffee and read the page on [transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

There are two options. In the first case, assume you lock the tables to prevent writes.Then, so long as B is doing the updatesin a single transaction then "read committed" will do you just fine. You won't end up with half the updates visible at any point.

In the second case, a "repeatable read" isolation level will ensure that once again, so long as B does its updates in a single transaction then all will be well. The "snapshot" that A sees of the database will be fixed at the point it started its transaction.

Of course, it might not make sense to be able to update an order that has been exported (because presumably someone is already trying to pack and ship my original order). I'm guessing that order/order-items might well be an example anyway.

(answer edited because Radek's comment suggested I'd not been clear and if there's one thing you need to be with concurrency issues then it is clear. Hopefully this is now)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I assume that B sends data in transaction so they appear together so the database is always contains correct data. What worries me is the concurrency issue when the export will be incorrect as B's transaction goes after first A's select and before second one. Theoretically, A should lock both tables, read data, and then release the lock so B would not be able to run code before A's reads. The root of the problem, of course, denormalisation, but it is inevitable. So is there a workaround?

Comment: `read committed` is not enough. You need `repeatable read` for transaction which contains exporting.

Comment: Unless he locks the tables as he discussed. Have I misread the question? Hmm - let me edit my answer, make sure it's clear.

Comment: Thanks! The one that locks the database when the transaction starts is exactly what I need.